# Eclipse installer Internal error: Registry directory not available

Tags: windows, eclipse, installation

I used to use the Oomph Eclipse installer like normal until I changed my user profile in the registry (to remove the annoying spaces). I have not had a single problem since then except with the eclipse installer. It keeps trying to look for the registry directory in the old user folder, which no longer exists. I know where my new registry is located, but I don't know how to tell the installer where to go.

[image]
[image]

So to be clear: I need to know how to tell the installer where to look for the registry directory.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've found an answer to my own question: Simply deleting the .eclipse folder in the new user's directory will fix it and it will now open correctly.

Comment: I found `rm -rf ~/.eclipse ~/.p2` and exiting/restarting the installer helped with a subsequent issue also related to having a new username.

Answer (score 2):

In my situation the users folder no longer existed so I had to add the old user name then continue the installation process. When asked to verify the installation location I changed it to my new users location.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when my new install decided to name my user folder `bdavi` instead of `bdavis`.  I just used `mklink` to create a direction junction (similar to a symbolic link) from the old username to the new one.

In an administrative command prompt...

`cd c:\users
mklink /j bdavis bdavi`

Answer (score 0):

This issue happened when I changed home directory of user at Mac. In my case, I manually deleted `.eclipse` and `.p2` folders of new home directory. I tested at `macOS Mojave`.

Answer (score 0):

delete .eclipse and .p2 file in new user folder then install eclipse.