# Eclipse - Internal Error: Registry directory not available

Tags: windows, eclipse, installation

I've been trying to install Eclipse with the Eclipse Installer form the Eclipse website and this error just keeps Popping up. I tried searching for similar ones, but nothing seems to help me and no, i don't think this is a duplicate question because i never changed users like OP did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41412983/eclipse-installer-internal-error-registry-directory-not-available). I also don't seem to find my .eclipse or .p2 folder in the Win 10 File explorer. and i just don't know what to do. Here's a screenshot: [image: C:/Users/User is my user directory and i never changed users nor did i have any folder in there named like this, which is odd.]

Ok, so after people asked me to provide more info, i will. It's a personal laptop, i have full admin permissions. Also, here are some screenshots of what is being put out if i put "dir C:\Users\User.p2" and "dir C:\Users\User.eclipse". "Datei nicht gefunden" is German for File not found. [image]

Comment: It seems you are using the _Eclipse Installer_ rather than installing Eclipse via a ZIP archive. If and only if you do not have other Eclipse installations you want to keep, delete the directory `C:\Users\User\.p2` completely. Caution: Deleting `C:\Users\User\.p2` will destroy any Eclipse installation done via the Eclipse Installer.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I never installed eclipse on this PC before nor do i have a .p2 folder in my User directory. Otherwise it would be a duplicate of the question linked.

Comment: I cannot see where you mentioned it. There are different ways to install Eclipse and your question does not tell what file you downloaded, what operating system you have, and exactly what steps you took before the error appeared. `.p2` and `.eclipse` are hidden directories, what do you exactly mean by _I also don't seem to find my .eclipse or .p2 folder_? What exactly did you do?

Comment: I use Win 10 and i installed the Eclipse Installer from the Eclipse Website, opened it and the error showed up. I looked for the folders mentioned in the other question and looked for the one you mentioned and they aren't there. There is no .p2 folder in the C:/Users/User directory and there also is no .eclipse folder there.

Comment: I just re-read your comment and i don't quite get how i am supposed to delete these directories if they are hidden. Do I have to do it through a cmd prompt?

Comment: Is this a personal machine or is it provided by your employer? If the latter, you may not be allowed to do this.

Comment: Please edit your question and add what you get on the command line for `dir C:\Users\User\.p2` and for `dir C:\Users\User\.eclipse`. You can also directly [download an Eclipse IDE package as ZIP file](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/).

Comment: @howlger Yeah, that's a good idea.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen It's a personal laptop, already edited the question.

Comment: Strange. For `set USERPROFILE` you get `USERPROFILE=C:\Users\User`, right? Is this a recent Windows 10? When did you download Eclipse Installer from where exactly (could you please share the download link)?

Comment: Ok, so i use Win 10 Version 21H1, it's not the newest one, i think it's from 2021. And yes, i did  get the output you described. I downloaded the eclipse installer from here: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ and i downloaded it right before posting the question.

Comment: Any hint when you click on _Details >>_? Instead of using the Eclipse Installer, you can [download an Eclipse IDE package as ZIP file](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/).

Comment: JavaIllegalStateError: Registry directory not available. I'll install it via zip, at this point i'm just curious.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so installing Eclipse via ZIP worked for me, but all of this was actually kind of useless, because I just got a new Workstation on which i can install eclipse the normal way. Still, thank all of you for your help, esepcially @howlger.